# How can I reply to a private message on a fan page using the Facebook Graph API in a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

How can I reply to a private message on a fan page using the Facebook Graph API in a Facebook app?

- I am able to retrieve private Messages from a fan page
- I am able to reply as a user using chat API (User to User only)
- I have valid tokens
- I have read_mailbox, read_page_mailboxes permissions, and the following permissions to the page too:

ADMINISTER,
EDIT_PROFILE,
CREATE_CONTENT,
MODERATE_CONTENT,
CREATE_ADS,
BASIC_ADMIN

I am doing it as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations).

[Some claim to have gotten around this](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/341975239249263?browse=search_511de4580d77f8062326065). How have they managed this?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to answers this question quite clearly.

From the docs:

```
**How to Reply**

Note that a page can only reply to a user's message. It cannot initiate a private message with a user. Also, a page can respond not more than twice to a user's message before the user has replied back.

You can reply to a user's message by issuing an HTTP POST to /CONVERSATION_ID/messages with the following parameters. A conversation ID look like t_id.216477638451347.

Parameter   Description          Type   Required
message     The body of reply   string      Y
```

Comment: Thanks @tommycrush, As stated by me earlier, I followed the documentation as is, still had no luck

1. Yes it is not initiated by a page but a user message Reply 
2. It is the first reply to a user message
3. Yes replying to a thread like t_id.1234444444
4. not replying to a message of a thread like m_id.12323232, m_mid.123231323

1. Is there something like Whitelisting of Private Message calls
2. Do we need to register some callback or something that is not specified in the documentation

Comment: Stackoverflow cannot help you further if you do not post your code. Edit your question and we can take a look.